# Alamofire JSON parsing of dictionary of arrays

Tags: swift, alamofire

Trying to parse this dictionary of Arrays.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  }
]
```

Is it possible to parse this Dictionary of arrays into an array of Model ([Artist]) for convenience.

```
AF.request(Constants.kGetArtistsAPIEndPoint).responseDecodable(of: [ArtistsResponse].self) { (response) in
            guard let artistsResponse = response.value else { return }
            print("ArtistsResponse is \(artistsResponse)")
            if let artists = artistsResponse.first {
                completion(artists)
            }
        }
```

My Artist class looks like below

```
struct ArtistsResponse: Codable {
    let artists: [Artist]
}

struct Artist: Codable {
    let artistId: String
    let name: String
    let username: String?
    let emailId: String?
    let address: Address?
    let phone: String?
    let website: String?
    let company: Company?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case artistId = "id"
        case name
        case username
        case emailId
        case address
        case phone
        case website
        case company
    }
}

struct Address: Codable {
    let street: String
    let suite: String?
    let city: String
    let zipcode: String
    let geo: GeoLocation
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case street
        case suite
        case city
        case zipcode
        case geo
    }
}

struct GeoLocation: Codable {
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude = "lat"
        case longitude = "lng"
    }
}
```

Tried with above code but it fails with below error code

```
Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))))
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible do decode that array of objects. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi @Claudio, Updated the code on what I have tried. Please have a look

Comment: Edit you question with ArtistsResponse class and any decoding error you get

Comment: Have updated the ArtistsResponse struct and decoding error from Alamofire @Claudio

Comment: Seeing the error, it's strange... How did you get that JSON? From where did you print it?

Comment: Is that the full JSON? Where's company struct? Also `[ArtistsResponse].self` would be at best `[Artist].self`, `ArtistsId` should be an Int

Comment: [Artist].self did the trick. Also thanks for pointing ArtistsId as Int. You can put the same as the answer. I will accept the same.